# How to use 'Connect to Server' on a Mac to access /var/www/html/ on the Pi

Tags: remote, filesystem, macos

When I use 'Connect to Server' on my Mac, one of the folders I want to access on my Raspberry Pi is `html` respectively `/var/www/html/`.

Double clicking on the 'Home Directory' brings up the usual list but it does not include neither the `html`-shortcut nor the `/var/www/html/`-directory itself.

How do I get to that directory from my Mac?

Comment: I'm looking exactly for that. I'm able to mount Pi's `/var/www/html` on the Mac with Netatalk but still haven't figured how to save the file that I open there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably out of luck. `var` on the Mac is actually a link -> `private/var`. OS X does its best to hide these directories from users, and AFAIK Finder refuses to let you access these remotely. (I can get to `/boot`, `/etc` provided I setup `netatalk` to map these on the Pi, I have not tried `/var`. Since SIP I have found no way to get finder to access `/` on the Pi.)

<del>I suggest to create a `~/home/html` directory and link this to `/var/www/html`.</del> does not work

This would not be without its problems, due to the differing users and permissions between the systems.

I usually just use `ftp`.

Answer (score 0):

It's taking you to `~` (home of the user) by default. You want to go to `/` (root), then `var`, then `www`, then `html` as necessary.

If you are using a terminal, you can simply:

```
sudo cd /var/www/html/
```

As for the Mac file explorer, it depends which version you are using, but what you are looking for should be labeled either "Parent", or "Go to parent", or "Up one level" or ".." or something along those lines. Do this until you hit the root directory (indicated by /), then simply navigate through to where you need to be.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do the "Parent", or "Go to parent", or "Up one level" or ".."  stuff at all. I can use SSH of course but really wanted to drag and drop from my mac to a finder folder on the Pi. Thanks for the ideas, they are appreciated.